# Returning value to pane from macro in ipython

Tags: ipython, canopy

I am new to python.. I am trying to create a macro. When selected a word and press f3 filedialog will come and  ill select a folder,ill get the occurance of that word in all files in tat folder displayed in the pane. The problem now is I couldn't return a value from macro editor to this pane.

Currently I am using this code

```
code_task = get_active_task()
python_pane = code_task.python_pane
python_pane.execute_command(u'print "searchstring"\n')
```

(consider searchstring contains the data)

When I try to execute it is telling tat undefined variable searchstring. Help me how to send the data from macro editor to the pane.

Comment: What application are these panes part of?

Comment: Check this link i found tat function here only http://docs.enthought.com/canopy/configure/ipython-scripting-api.html

Comment: I've added the tag canopy - that might get someone who knows about that to look at it.

Comment: Can you say a bit more about what you want this macro to do? What do you actually want to do? (Just guessing that a pythonic answer will not actually involve using a macro, but might be something different)

Comment: @gabe I have posted a part of the code.. The macro is used for searching. Select a string and press f3,thiis macro ill pop up a filedialog and v ill select a folder.The string ill be searched in the folder and the search result should be displayed in the pane window.Nw the data from the macro'sconsole is not visibel to tat pane.Thats the prob

Comment: Ok, better. But what do you want the search to do? e.g. Are you doing find and replace in a bunch of text?